# In MySQL, how to avoid duplicated selections in a nested selection?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like below:

| person_id | school_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 456 |

Now I would like to calculate a `school_rating` field, which is done by using the `school_id` field to fetch some date from other tables and doing the math.

And I want to fetch this `school_rating` field together with the other 2 fields.

So the returned table should be like

| person_id | school_id | school_rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 123 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 456 | 3.5 |

I know how to do it by joining tables together, but the problem is that, as shown above, the calculation for `schoold_id = 123` will be done TWICE.

I am wondering how to avoid that.

It seems that MySQL used to have cache, but was switched off since version 8.0.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicate results.

Comment: @Barmar but I do need a `school_id` for each `person_id`.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT will not help because of different person_id. You should use extra group by for school id. AND don't forget to add MIN or MAX(person_id). otherwise it will occur error

Comment: @Barmar If only distinct `school_id`s are preserved, the `person_id = 2` will have `school_id = null`, is that correct?

Comment: if you dont want to calculate twice, first you should calculate school rating for each school_id, then join to persons table.

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə Ah.. I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: if it helps, please vote up)  you are welcome)

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə Sorry, one more question. Let's say I have 100 `school_id` in another table called `school`, but I only care about the 2 mentioned in the table, aka, 123 and 456. Ideally, I only need to calculate `school_score` for these two. But using your suggested approach, I will have to calculate a score for all 100 `school_id`s. Not sure if that is correct. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: So just get DISTINC ids for school_id(SELECT DISTINCT school_id FROM persons) , then use your calculation by this ids(where in (IDS)), then join.

Comment: Sorry my previous description is not accurate. I don't care about all `school_id` in the table, I only care about those related to the `person_id`s that are filtered out by some other conditions. For example, there are 3 `school_id` in the table, 123, 456 and 789. After selecting the `person_id`s, only a few rows are returned, and these rows only relate to two `school_id`s, 123 and 456, but not 789. But using `select DISTINC ids from school_id`, 789 will be calculated as well. I am wondering how to avoid that. Note that I want complete it in only one access to the DB. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to calculate rating twice, first you should calculate school rating for each `school_id`, then `join` the result to `persons` table